# Alignment of Roman enumeration list

Tags: enumerate, roman-numerals, roman

I am trying to create Roman enumerating list.

I am using package:

```
\usepackage{enumerate}
```

Here is my code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*]
\item \textbf{\textit{First}}
\item \textbf{\textit{Second}} 
\item \textbf{\textit{Third}} 
\end{enumerate}
```

Graphical result is:
[image]

So result is:

```
  I First
 II Second
III Third
```

How can I change the result to:

```
 I   First
 II  Second
 III Third
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With enumitem (not enumerate):

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*,align=left]
\item \textbf{\textit{First}}
\item \textbf{\textit{Second}}
\item \textbf{\textit{Third}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can roman letters be italic?

Comment: \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),align=parleft,font=\itshape]
   \item 
   \item 
  \end{enumerate}